# Kotlin: How convert from Set to Map?

Tags: kotlin

I have `Set<FlagFilter>` and I need to convert it to `Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter>`.

I tried doing it like this:

```kotlin
val result: Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter> =
     target
        .takeIf { !it.isEmpty() }
         ?.map { mapOf(it.javaClass to it) }
         ?: emptyMap<>()
```

but instead of a `Map` it turns out to be a `List` and I get a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter>
Found: List<Map<Class<FlagFilter>, FlagFilter>>
```

What am I doing wrong? As if there is not enough operation, but I do not understand yet which one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html) extension function:

```kotlin
val result: Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter> =
    target.associateBy { it.javaClass }
```

Or if you want to fix your code, remove the excessive call of mapOf(). Just convert your Set to List of Pairs, and then call toMap() to create a map:

```kotlin
val result: Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter> =
    target.map { it.javaClass to it }.toMap()
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` isn't anything to do with the `Map` type - it's a functional programming term (coming from a broader mathematical concept) that basically means a function that *maps* each input value to an output value.

So it's a *transformation* or *conversion* that takes a collection of items, transforms each one, and results in another collection with the same number of items. In Kotlin, you get a `List` of items (unless you're working with a `Sequence`, in which case you get another `Sequence` that yields the same number of items).

It's worth getting familiar with the [kotlin.collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) package - there's lots of useful stuff in there! But each function has a specific purpose, in terms of how they process the collection and what they return:

- `map` - returns a new value for each item
- `onEach` - returns the original items (allows you to do something with each, then continue processing the collection)
- `forEach` - returns nothing (allows you to do something with each, but as a final operation - you can't chain another operation, it's *terminal*)
- `filter` - returns a subset of the original items, matching a predicate
- `first` - returns a single item, matching a predicate
- `reduce` - returns a single item, transforming the values to produce a single result
- `count` - returns a single item, based on an attribute of the collection (not the values themselves)

There's more but you get the idea - some things transform, some things pass-through, some things give you an identically sized collection, or a potentially smaller one, or a single value. `map` is just the one that takes a collection, and gives you a collection of the same size where every item has been (potentially) altered.

Like *Vadik* says, use one of the `associate*` functions to turn values into a `Map` object, effectively transforming each item in the collection into a `Map.Entry`. Which is technically *mapping it* to a mapping, so I wasn't *totally accurate* earlier when I said it's nothing to do with `Map`s, but I figured I'd save this thought til the end ;)